# There is a problem when applying thymeleaf-layout-dialect

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8, thymeleaf

spring boot 2.2.5, openjdk-1.8.0.252-2.b09

## I get the following error.

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
tried to access method org.thymeleaf.engine.StandardModelFactory.removeAttribute(Lorg/thymeleaf/model/IOpenElementTag;Lorg/thymeleaf/engine/AttributeName;)Lorg/thymeleaf/model/IOpenElementTag; from class org.thymeleaf.engine.StandardModelFactory$removeAttribute
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.thymeleaf.engine.StandardModelFactory.removeAttribute(Lorg/thymeleaf/model/IOpenElementTag;Lorg/thymeleaf/engine/AttributeName;)Lorg/thymeleaf/model/IOpenElementTag; from class org.thymeleaf.engine.StandardModelFactory$removeAttribute
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.StandardModelFactory$removeAttribute.call(Unknown Source)
    at nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf.decorators.DecorateProcessor.doProcess(DecorateProcessor.groovy:112)
    at nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf.decorators.DecoratorProcessor.super$5$doProcess(DecoratorProcessor.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor134.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1262)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:144)
    at nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf.decorators.DecoratorProcessor.doProcess(DecoratorProcessor.groovy:81)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeModelProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeModelProcessor.java:77)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementModelProcessor.process(AbstractElementModelProcessor.java:98)
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementModelProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:649)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1510)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.OpenElementTag.beHandled(OpenElementTag.java:205)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:282)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:290)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.GatheringModelProcessable.process(GatheringModelProcessable.java:78)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleCloseElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1640)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.java:388)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler$InlineMarkupAdapterPreProcessorHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:322)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.inline.OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.java:220)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:164)
    at org.attoparser.HtmlElement.handleCloseElementEnd(HtmlElement.java:169)
    at org.attoparser.HtmlMarkupHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(HtmlMarkupHandler.java:412)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupEventProcessorHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(MarkupEventProcessorHandler.java:473)
    at org.attoparser.ParsingElementMarkupUtil.parseCloseElement(ParsingElementMarkupUtil.java:201)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseBuffer(MarkupParser.java:725)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:301)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:666)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:362)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:189)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1373)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1057)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.doFilter(ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.java:64)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1639)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

=========================================================================================

## The following is a full of pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>net.ec</groupId>
    <artifactId>ec-admin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ec-admin</name>
    <description>ec-admin</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-data</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>webjars-locator-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
            
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.qlrm</groupId>
            <artifactId>qlrm</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bgee.log4jdbc-log4j2</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4jdbc-log4j2-jdbc4.1</artifactId>
            <version>1.16</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>                      
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <includeSystemScope>true</includeSystemScope>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                            <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor
                            </processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <testSource>1.8</testSource>
                    <testTarget>1.8</testTarget>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:deprecation</compilerArgument>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The following is a result of 'mvn dependency:resolve'

```
[INFO] The following files have been resolved:
[INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO]    ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO]    org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.12.1:compile
[INFO]    org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO]    jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
[INFO]    org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.25:runtime
[INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.10.2:compile
[INFO]    com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.10.2:compile
[INFO]    com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.10.2:compile
[INFO]    com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.10.2:compile
[INFO]    com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.10.2:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.31:compile
[INFO]    org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.31:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:2.0.2:compile
[INFO]    org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:9.0.31:compile
[INFO]    org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.18.Final:compile
[INFO]    org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.1.Final:compile
[INFO]    com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.5:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:3.4.2:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO]    jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:jar:2.2.3:compile
[INFO]    jakarta.transaction:jakarta.transaction-api:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO]    org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.4.12.Final:compile
[INFO]    org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.24.0-GA:compile
[INFO]    net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.10.8:compile
[INFO]    antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO]    org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.1.1.Final:compile
[INFO]    org.dom4j:dom4j:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO]    org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO]    org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO]    org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO]    com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:3.0.8:compile
[INFO]    org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex:jar:1.8.1:compile
[INFO]    com.sun.xml.fastinfoset:FastInfoset:jar:1.2.16:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:5.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:5.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.security:spring-security-data:jar:5.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO]    javax.activation:javax.activation-api:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.security:spring-security-test:jar:5.2.2.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.2.4.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring5:jar:3.0.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-java8time:jar:3.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-layout-dialect:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO]    nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-expression-processor:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO]    org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:jar:3.0.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    ognl:ognl:jar:3.1.12:compile
[INFO]    org.attoparser:attoparser:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.unbescape:unbescape:jar:1.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5:jar:3.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:test
[INFO]    net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:test
[INFO]    net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:test
[INFO]    org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:test
[INFO]    jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO]    org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.5.2:test
[INFO]    org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.5.2:test
[INFO]    org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.0:test
[INFO]    org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO]    org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.5.2:test
[INFO]    org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.5.2:test
[INFO]    org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.5.2:test
[INFO]    org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.5.2:test
[INFO]    org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:3.1.0:test
[INFO]    org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.13.2:test
[INFO]    org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.1:test
[INFO]    org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:3.1.0:test
[INFO]    net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.10.8:test
[INFO]    org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.6:test
[INFO]    org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO]    com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO]    org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.6.3:test
[INFO]    org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.18.12:compile (optional) 
[INFO]    com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:jar:4.2.2:compile
[INFO]    com.querydsl:querydsl-core:jar:4.2.2:compile
[INFO]    com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0:compile
[INFO]    com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile
[INFO]    com.mysema.commons:mysema-commons-lang:jar:0.2.4:compile
[INFO]    com.infradna.tool:bridge-method-annotation:jar:1.13:compile
[INFO]    javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO]    com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:jar:4.2.2:compile
[INFO]    com.querydsl:querydsl-codegen:jar:4.2.2:compile
[INFO]    com.mysema.codegen:codegen:jar:0.6.8:compile
[INFO]    org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler:ecj:jar:4.3.1:compile
[INFO]    org.reflections:reflections:jar:0.9.9:compile
[INFO]    com.google.code.findbugs:annotations:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO]    org.webjars:jquery:jar:3.4.1:compile
[INFO]    org.webjars:webjars-locator-core:jar:0.41:compile
[INFO]    io.github.classgraph:classgraph:jar:4.8.44:compile
[INFO]    com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.10.2:compile
[INFO]    org.webjars.npm:angular__http:jar:2.4.10:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.9:compile
[INFO]    commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO]    commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO]    org.modelmapper:modelmapper:jar:2.3.5:compile
[INFO]    org.qlrm:qlrm:jar:2.0.2:compile
[INFO]    org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.12.1:compile
[INFO]    org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.12.1:compile
[INFO]    org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO]    org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO]    org.mybatis:mybatis:jar:3.4.6:compile
[INFO]    org.mybatis:mybatis-spring:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO]    com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:jar:7.4.1.jre8:compile
[INFO]    org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.11:compile
[INFO]    org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.13:compile
[INFO]    commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.13:compile
[INFO]    org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:jar:3.0.4:compile
[INFO]    org.bgee.log4jdbc-log4j2:log4jdbc-log4j2-jdbc4.1:jar:1.16:compile
```

1. If I delete the layout:decorator code, no error remains. However, the layout does not apply
2. No error when using jdk 9 version.

What is the problem?

Comment: Can you post the output of `mvn dependency:resolve`?

Comment: Please add your full list of dependencies and try to run `mvn dependencies:tree` to see what gets pulled in. Looks like you are mixing up some versions.

Comment: i add a full of pom.xml and a result of 'mvn dependency:resolve'

Comment: The error disappeared after removing unnecessary groovy dependency with version specified in pom.xml